# perform acf plot for each type of group in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Say, here the mydata (little part)

```
transport<- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L), .Label = c("01.01.2001", "01.02.2001", "01.03.2001", 
"01.04.2001", "01.05.2001", "01.06.2001", "01.07.2001", "01.08.2001", 
"01.09.2001", "01.10.2001", "01.11.2001", "01.12.2001"), class = "factor"), 
    Market_82 = c(7000L, 7272L, 7668L, 7869L, 8057L, 8428L, 8587L, 
    8823L, 8922L, 9178L, 9306L, 9439L, 3725L, 4883L, 8186L, 7525L, 
    6335L, 4252L, 5642L, 1326L, 8605L, 3501L, 1944L, 7332L), 
    transport = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("plane", "train"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
"Market_82", "transport"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

group variable - Transport.

For each type of transport i must get `acf plot` of time series.

something like this
[image]

[image]

How perform acf plot for each transport?
I have a lot of groups. How to do that plots were in folder
C:/Users/admin/Documents/myplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `Acf` from `forecast`

```
library(forecast)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
lapply(split(transport['Market_82'], transport$transport), Acf)
```

---

If we also want the title, then

```
lst <- lapply(split(transport['Market_82'], transport$transport), acf, plot = FALSE)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
lapply(names(lst), function(x) plot(lst[[x]], main = x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

akrun's answer is spot on. Since you tagged the question with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) you could also use `ggAcf` from the forcast package.

The first step is to `split` your data.

```
transport_split <- split(transport, transport$transport)
```

If you want to include the respective element of column `transport` in the title, subtitle etc. try with `Map`

```
out <- Map(
    f = function(x, y)
      forecast::ggAcf(x$Market_82) + labs(title = y),
    x = transport_split,
    y = names(transport_split)
  )

out$train
```

[image]